# Distance to an equator

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, spheres

Let $\mathbb{S}^n$ be the round sphere, $p_0$ be the north-pole and $T$ be the equator whose center is $p_0$. Given a point $p$ on the sphere, **how do we calculate the (spherical, intrinsic) distance of $p$ to $T$?** It certainly has to do with the inner product $\langle p, p_0 \rangle$, but I am unsure about the explicit formula. If $p$ is next to $\pm p_0$, $d(p, T)$ is next to $\pi/2$, and if $p$ is next to $T$, obviously $d(p, T)$ is next to $0$. And it is easy to see that $d(p, T)$ is even with respect to $\langle p, p_0 \rangle$. I suspect $d(p, T) = |\arcsin \langle p, p_0 \rangle|$.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ and $q$ be two points on the surface of the sphere, of radius $R$, subtending a central angle of $\theta$ (along any great circle through $p$ and $q$).  Then 
$$  \frac{\langle p,q \rangle}{||p|| \, ||q||} = \frac{\langle p,q \rangle}{R^2} = \cos \theta  \text{.}  $$

Any great circle through $p_0$ meets $T$ perpendicularly.  So the angle $\theta$ satisfying 
$$  \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} = \cos \theta  $$
is the angle between $p_0$ and $p$ along a great circle perpendicular to $T$.  If $0 \leq \theta\leq \pi/2$, the (smallest) angle between $p$ and $T$ is $\varphi = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$.  If $\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, then $\varphi = \theta - \pi/2$.  (It can help to draw a picture here, where in one case $p$ is in the same hemisphere bounded by $T$ as is $p_0$ and in the other case, $p$ is in the opposite hemisphere.)  Combining all this, 
$$ \varphi = \left| \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta \right| = \left| \frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right)  \right|  \text{.}  $$

Finally, the distance along the great circle through $p$ perpendicular to $T$ is $\varphi R$, so
$$  d(p,T) = R \left| \frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right)  \right|  \text{.}  $$

If this is the unit sphere, $R = 1$ and this simplifies a bit.

---

Suppose we now want to solve that for $\langle p_0,p \rangle$.  \begin{align*}
\frac{d(p,T)}{R} &= \left| \frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right)  \right|  \\
    &\in \pm \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right) \right)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\cos\left( \frac{d(p,T)}{R} \right) &= \cos \pm \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right) \right)  \\
    &= \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right) \right)  &&  \text{cosine is even}  \\
    &= \cos \frac{\pi}{2} \cos \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right) + \sin \frac{\pi}{2} \sin \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right)  \\
    &= \sin \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
The range of arccosine is $[0, \pi]$, and sine is nonnegative for all those angles, so \begin{align*}
\cos\left( \frac{d(p,T)}{R} \right) &= \frac{+\sqrt{R^4 - \langle p_0,p \rangle^2}}{R^2}  \\
    &= \sqrt{1 - \left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right)^2}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
so
$$  \left( \frac{\langle p_0,p \rangle}{R^2} \right)^2 = 1 - \cos^2 \left( \frac{d(p,T)}{R} \right)  $$
and then \begin{align*}
\langle p_0,p \rangle &= \pm R^2 \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \left( \frac{d(p,T)}{R} \right)}  \\
&= \pm R^2 \sqrt{\sin^2 \left( \frac{d(p,T)}{R} \right)}  \\
&= \pm R^2 \sin \left( \frac{d(p,T)}{R} \right)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
This is the best we can do, because $d(p,T)$ doesn't contain information about which hemisphere $p$ is in.  (This missing information was first indicated by the "$\pm$".)  We choose the positive root if $p$ is in the same hemisphere as $p_0$ and the negative root if $p$ is in the other hemisphere (and the square root has the value zero if $p$ is on $T$, so either choice of sign is fine).

Comment: Can we solve for $\langle p,p_0 \rangle$?

Comment: @EduardoLonga : THat would be a new question.  However, I'll edit in a second answer.

Comment: we can further simplify the last square root to get a sine, right?

Comment: @EduardoLonga : Yes we can and I have (now, together with a dropped square of $R$ near the end).  The result shouldn't be so surprising; The angle between $p$ and $p_0$ is complementary to the angle between $p$ and $T$, so while $\langle p, p_0 \rangle$ is proportional to $\cos \theta$, it is also proportional to the complementary cosine (that is, *sine*) of the complementary angle.